# My minecraft fish just stay at the bottom of my aquarium and spin

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have these tropical fish in a tank that wont move at all, they just stay at the bottom and spin. I want them to move but the just wont.
I tried to look up some answers and saw that if the source is inly at the top they just get pushed to the bottom, but my water source is everywhere and theyre not getting pushed down. They just like to spin.
I will admit my aquarium is not the roomiest but my house is not big so i cant make much room for more aquarium, it has a length of 7 blocks, width of 4 blocks, and a height of 3 blocks.
Im playing on a ps5 if that matters.
Is there any way to fix my fish? If not im replacing them with axolotl

Comment: Update they are no longer spinning

Comment: I've seen this before and I'm guessing this is just a pathfinding bug and I do see it occasionally but like you seem to have found they usually snap out of it after a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a pathfinding bug. Make sure the bottom of the aquarium is NOT made out of any blocks that are not full blocks (examples include any lower slab and Soul Sand). Even when it is perfect, pathfinding may get stuck at times.

Comment: I have sand but the sand is covered in coral and seaweed. But the front wall is glass